# How to display different links for logged in and logged out users?

Tags: wordpress

When a user is not logged in I am trying to show

```
Support || Log In
```

When they are logged out it should say

```
Support || Log Out
```

Here is the code I tried to use to get this to work

```
    <div class="fr">
            <ul class="rss">

                <li><a href="http:/jfdfjdf.com/wp-login.php">Support</a></li>
                <li><?php if (is_user_logged_in() ) { echo " <a href=" . wp_logout_url() . " title=\"Logout\">Logout</a>";}?></li>
                <li><?php else if (!is_user_logged_in() ) { echo " <a href="fdjdjfd.com" title=\"Logout\">Member Login</a>";}?></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

But it is not working can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 3):

Your code has a syntax error:

```
<li><?php else if (!is_user_logged_in() ) { echo " <a href="http://example.com/wp-login.php" title=\"Logout\">Member Login</a>";}?></li>
```

You should escape the double-quotes:

```
<li><?php else if (!is_user_logged_in() ) { echo " <a href=\"http://example.com/wp-login.php\" title=\"Logout\">Member Login</a>";}?></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the result of your function, but to start you were not escaping properly.  Secondly, why not just use one `li` to house the correct link as follows:

```
<div class="fr">             
    <ul class="rss">                  
        <li><a href="http://example.com/go/wp-login.php">Support</a></li>                 
        <li><?php if (is_user_logged_in() ) { 
                echo " <a href=\"" . wp_logout_url() . "\" title=\"Logout\">Logout</a>";
            }else{ 
                echo " <a href=\"http://example.com/" title=\"Login\">Member Login</a>";
            } ?>
        </li>             
    </ul>         
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
<div class="fr">
  <ul class="rss">
    <li><a href="http://example.com/wp-login.php">Support</a></li>
    <li>
      <?php if (is_user_logged_in() ): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url() ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>
      <?php else: ?> 
        <a href="http://example.com/wp-login.php" title="Logout">Member Login</a>
      <?php endif ?>
    </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Your mistake is that you should not insert anything between closing `}` and `else` keyword. Also, in templates, oldschool `if`, `while`, `foreach` form should be used - see above.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to display content for users with a shortcode. Post this into functions.php

```
// When member is logged in [memberin]

add_shortcode( 'memberin', 'member_check_shortcode' ); 
function member_check_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
function member_check_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
  if ( is_user_logged_in() && !is_null( $content ) && !is_feed() )
return $content;
return '';
}

// When member is logged out [memberout]

add_shortcode( 'memberout', 'member_check_shortcode_out' );
function member_check_shortcode_out( $atts, $content = null ) {
  if (!is_user_logged_in() && !is_null( $content ) && !is_feed() )
return $content;
return '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from coding you can always use a plugin called [Nav Menu Roles](https://wordpress.org/plugins/nav-menu-roles/)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing `?php else if (!is_user_logged_in() )` to just `?php if (!is_user_logged_in() )` ?

Comment: You should also be able to just remove the requirement of the second 'if' statement as if they are logged in do X, else do Y -- it shouldn't matter for what the resultant is if they are not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following?

```
<div class="fr">
    <ul class="rss">
        <li><a href="http://example.com/wp-login.php">Support</a></li>
        <?php if (is_user_logged_in() ) { echo " <li><a href=" . wp_logout_url() . " title=\"Logout\">Logout</a></li>";}?>
        <?php else if (!is_user_logged_in() ) { echo " <li><a href="http://example.com/wp-login.php" title=\"Logout\">Member Login</a></li>";}?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I moved the php if statements so you don't get empty *li* elements. You should still do the escaping that others have noticed.

Comment: Your example is not escaping properly.  You would want to escape the quotes in your links and add a containing quote to house the link itself.

Comment: Yes. I didn't notice the quotes. I edited to better explain what I noticed.

Comment: Your solution can also be simplified by moving the <li> tags to the outside of the php code.  Also, it looks like you're still missing some escaping quotes for the container of the links.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to functions.php in your theme or create a plugin.
Change 'menu' to the menu location eg. 'primary-menu' in your theme. 
Change 'logged-in' to the name of the logged in menu and logged out respectively.

```
<?php
  function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {

    if( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
        $args['menu'] = 'logged-in';
    } else { 
        $args['menu'] = 'logged-out';
    } 
        return $args;
    }
    add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
?>
```

referenced from: [WPBeginner](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-show-different-menus-to-logged-in-users-in-wordpress/)